# Performance lose after adding icons to tabs

Tags: android, tabs, icons

I am adding custom views that contain ImageViews to tabs.

Here I get layouts:

```
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.custom_actionbar_tab_1, null);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_28799);

        LinearLayout view2 = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.custom_actionbar_tab_2, null);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) view2.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_20321);

        LinearLayout view3 = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.custom_actionbar_tab_3, null);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) view3.findViewById(R.id.image3);
        image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_39547);
```

And here I set the custom views to the tabs:

```
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(view)
                .setTabListener(this));

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(view2)
                .setTabListener(this));

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(view3)
                .setTabListener(this));
```

But when I test it on emulator the app slows rapidly down and it takes forever to swipe between tabs. Icons are in one drawable folder. Somebody similar issues?

Comment: I am not sure I would trust the emulator, when testing for performance. Have you tested on an actual device?

Comment: I am using genymotion and this is pretty fast for an emulator... since I added the icons to tabs the app slowed down. When I remove the icons it is fast.

Comment: ok I find it out. It was the image size that slowed down the performance. I adjusted the size for every denisty

Comment: Excellent, make sure you add that as an answer here and accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the image sizes. I adjusted it for every denisty and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try my code below for tabs with icon / text, Make sure you extend in TabActivity

```
private void setTabs()
{
    addTab("Tab1", R.drawable.icon1, Tab1.class);
    addTab("Tab2", R.drawable.icon2, Tab2.class);
    addTab("Tab3", R.drawable.icon3, Tab3.class);
    addTab("Tab4", R.drawable.icon4, Tab4.class);
    addTab("Tab5", R.drawable.icon5, Tab5.class);
}

private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
{
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#d3d3d3"/>
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Then apply your own style for the tabs. This is just basically it. IF you encounter crashes on emulator still, I recommend you to try genymotion.